# Assign values to variable from list by indexes

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python like this

```
["Test1","Test2"]
```

I want to write something like this

```
Var1, var2 = the list above
```

So that the Var1 take value `Test1` and Var2 take the value of `Test2`
Can i do that and is that even possible

I have tried but i did't get a result and i wanted to google it but i don't know what to write

Comment: You can do this in Python, as long as the number of variables on the left side is equal to the length of your list or tuple. `a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: `I have tried but i did't get a result` what have you tried and what was result? cause the example you stated is exactly the answer for your question i.e. `a, b = ['Test1', 'Test2']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ["Test1", "Test2"]
Var1, Var2 = my_list

print(Var1)  # Output: Test1
print(Var2)  # Output: Test2
```

bear in mind that if the number of variables and elements in the list do not match, you will get a ValueError